# How to increase limit of progressbar in bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having problem with width of Progressbar in bootstrap.
I am adding values of 3 progressbars in last progress bar.
But its getting beyond 100. 
e.g progressBar 1 - 25
    progressBar 2 - 45
    progressBar 3 - 45
25+45+45 = 115
Now its getting beyond limit of progressbar 
So can I increase max width to 500 or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that really a good idea? Wouldn't it confuse people when they are 115% done with something?

Why not scale the values of the progress bars? Since you have 3, they should each constitute 33.3% of the total.

http://jsfiddle.net/VQS2k/109/

### HTML

```
    <div class="progress progress-striped">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success check_bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 70%">
        <span class="sr-only">70% Complete (success)</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="progress progress-striped">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info check_bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 75%">
        <span class="sr-only">75% Complete</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="progress progress-striped">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning check_bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%">
        <span class="sr-only">60% Complete (warning)</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    Overall Progress
  <div class="progress progress-striped">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger bar-total" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="0" style="">
    <span class="sr-only"></span>
  </div>
```

### js

```
var total = 0;
var bars = 0;
$('.check_bar').each(function(i,v) {
    var value = $(this).attr('aria-valuenow');
    total += parseInt(value);
    bars  += parseInt(i);
  });

  $('.bar-total').css('width', total/bars+'%').attr('aria-valuenow', total/bars);
```